# Как определить, что произошел обмена значениями в DataFrame

Tags: python, алгоритм, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Я новичок в Python и тяжело дается эта задачка оптимальным путем.
У меня есть база с КПП, в которой есть id сотрудника и номер его пропуска. У некоторых сотрудников есть много номеров пропуска- это странно, но примем этот как факт. Мне надо написать код, который бы определил, кто из сотрудников прошел по чужому пропуску, другими словами, между сотрудниками произошел обмен пропусками и это надо идентифицировать: От кого -> Кому-> Какой номер пропуска. id сотрудника определяется по камере на КПП. [Чистый DataFrame, без обмена](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/wAc_kBnnV0sF1g). Он чистый, тут нет никакого обмена. Выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут [датасет](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/6uBM3u0shszYmg), в котором есть обмен между двумя сотрудниками (обмен показан стрелками):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сделал по "чистому" датасету словарь (номера пропусков через пробел), чтобы по нему сравнивать:

```
# Создание справочника сотрудника
def make_directory(df):
    #df.rename(columns={' IMSI':'IMSI',' IMEISV':'IMEISV',' Наименование': 'Наименование',' Дата создания':'Дата создания' ,' Время изменения состояния': 'Время изменения состояния',' Время последнего взаимодействия':'Время последнего взаимодействия',' Имя зоны':'Имя зоны',' Имя устройства':'Имя устройства',' Компонент устройства':'Компонент устройства',' Состояние':'Состояние'}, inplace=True)

    res = df.groupby("id сотрудника")["Номер пропуска"].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([str(i) for i in x])).to_frame()
    return res
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По итогу у меня код получается с тремя циклами for и очень длинный. Помогите решить эту задачу.

В результате, должно быть, что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
d1 = pd.read_csv("subset.csv", index_col=0).drop_duplicates()
d2 = pd.read_csv("anomaly_subset.csv", index_col=0).drop_duplicates()
d1.columns = d2.columns

res = d2.merge(d1, how="left", indicator=True).query("_merge == 'left_only'")
res = d1.merge(res, on="IMSI", suffixes=("_from", "_to")).drop(columns="_merge")
```

результат:

```
In [170]: res
Out[170]:
        IMEISV_from             IMSI         IMEISV_to
0  3573320886721407  250011764226668   136250051790829
1   136250051790829  250011773707303  3573320886721407
```

Comment: спасибо огромное